# How to use TortoiseSVN to merge a revision to self branch

Tags: tortoisesvn

As title, do you know how to use TortoiseSVN to merge a revision to self branch?

Thanks,
Ricky

Comment: What is "self branch"?  Maybe you should elaborate.

Comment: self branch want to express : merge revison from "A" branc to "A" branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To SVN all branches are just plain folders, so you merge one folder to another.

- Right-click on destination folder, TortoiseSVN > Merge
- choose Reintegrate a branch (I suppose, it depends on what a "self branch" mean)
- enter path to source folder and click Next (path is easiest to obtain via Repo-browser)
- choose additional options (usually just leave it like it is)
- click Test merge to see what will happen
- if satisfied then click Merge (conflicts are not a problem in general case, but you need to resolve them using your sharp eyes, bright mind, steady fingers and favorite text editor)
- if all goes well and after all conflicts are resolved commit the changes

**EDIT**: Now that the meaning of "self branch" is revealed maybe it is better to use third merge method, option "Merge two different trees". This is the most general method, because you are able to choose all parameters by hand.

- Right-click on the folder you want to update with older changes, TortoiseSVN > Merge
- choose "Merge two different trees" (they will not be really different)
- enter only start and end revision numbers, and don't change the paths, and click Next
- same as last 4 steps in previous list